# ExceptionInInitializerError with Firebase and Facebook

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I recently upgraded firebase to the latest versions and am now using a custom token generated by our servers to authenticate.  I am also doing a custom initialization of my firebase instance as explained here https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html . The initialization is done as the 3rd line of my application onCreate method (after calling super and setting a static instance variable) so it is as early as I can make it.

I get the following exception, but it's not consistently reproducible so it seems like some kind of race condition between firebase and facebook sdks.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager.zzcb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.zzar(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.zzbf(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzat.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzat.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfUrlConnection.instrument(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.createConnection(GraphRequest.java:1410)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.toHttpConnection(GraphRequest.java:1070)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1158)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1134)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1118)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1093)
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:987)
        at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:207)
        at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$100(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:47)
        at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.coffeemeetsbagel. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:240)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager.zzcb(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.zzar(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.zzbf(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzat.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzat.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfUrlConnection.instrument(Unknown Source) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.createConnection(GraphRequest.java:1410) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.toHttpConnection(GraphRequest.java:1070) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1158) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1134) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1118) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1093) 
        at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:987) 
        at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:207)
```

**Update** Removing the firebase performance plugin seems to resolve the issue; however, I want the automatic tracking provided by the plugin so I'd like to find a solution that allows me to use both firebase and facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook says their android sdk is not currently compatible with the firebase performance plugin.

**https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2046702775626929/**

Comment: could you please provide any reference for that? I've been having the same problem, and is there anyway to make these two run together?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue seems to be Facebook SDK trying to do a network request before Firebase Performance has initialised. I found a solution to force Firebase to initialise before facebook.

1. Remove both "init providers" for Firebase and Facebook in your Android Manifest. These are used in each SDK to automatically initialise each library.
   2.You can then initialise each library manually from the Application onCreate method, with Firebase called before Facebook.

In you AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <!--Init Firebase manually in Application class-->
    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
        tools:node="remove"
        />

    <!--Init Facebook manually in Application class-->
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.FacebookInitProvider"
        tools:node="remove"/>
```

In your application class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
}
```

I don't think this is a great solution, but it does the job for now, until either Facebook or Firebase update their libraries to stop this conflict during application start.